# Semantic-UI/NPM does not create any files upon "gulp build"

Tags: html, css, node.js, semantic-ui

new user of Semantic-UI here, and would love to start learning it. I have avoided things like NPM and gulp for all of my short web development career and figured with this new project it would be a good time to learn it.

The issue that I am currently having is that setting up Semantic-UI, 1-to-1 with the video tutorial, I'm receiving no output files. My flow currently, for setting up my new project, is as follows:

1. Create new, empty ASP.NET website in Visual Studio 2015
2. Navigate to the project folder in Node.js cmd prompt
3. run npm install semantic-ui --save
4. From here, I follow the video tutorial at [Semantic's site](http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html)

In the video, nearing the end of it, you'll see "[gulp] created: <css/js file>" several times. I have been looking for the dist/ folder and it doesn't even create that. Does anyone know why this is happening? It takes no longer than 150ms for the "package"/"build" tasks to complete on my end, but it shows several seconds in the tutorial video. I just can't understand what I am doing wrong if I am following it verbatim...

Comment: Hi, please provide some information: which version of node do you have (`node --version`), what is the exact output you get when you run `npm install semantic-ui --save` and what happens when you run `gulp build` from the video?

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm install` in project's root. For some reason this step is missing in documentation.